RTC ice candidate gathering is not triggered when my call starts from callee side
There are my idea steps that I try to implement:

callee start a live and wait to a new caller join
caller join and then send offer and establish peer-to-peer following WebRTC workflow normally
Actual: I try to log and not see any ice candidate triggered

server.js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*', // You can specify specific origins instead of '*' for better security
        methods: ['GET', 'POST']
    }
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/lives/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'callee.html'));
});

app.get('/view/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'caller.html'));
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New client connected:', socket.id);

    socket.on('start-lives', ({ role, roomId }) => {
        socket.data = { role, roomId };
        socket.join(roomId);
        console.log("Owner connected");
    });

    socket.on('join', (data) => {
        socket.join(data.roomId);
        socket.to(data.roomId).emit('join', socket.id);
        console.log(`Client ${socket.id} joined room ${data.roomId}`);
    });

    socket.on('offer', (data) => {
        socket.to(data.roomId).emit('offer', data.sdp);
    });

    socket.on('answer', (data) => {
        console.log("transfer:answer");
        socket.to(data.roomId).emit('answer', data.sdp);
    });

    socket.on('candidate', (data) => {
        socket.to(data.roomId).emit('candidate', data.candidate);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected:', socket.data);
    });
});

server.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 8080');
});

callee.js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Livestream</title>
    <style>
        #lives-container {
            width: 50vw;
        }

        #lives-video {
            background: url('https://marketplace.canva.com/EAEyZPDsh-4/1/0/1600w/canva-dark-purple-futuristic-stream-starting-soon-twitch-background-9h5ocxbndVU.jpg') no-repeat center;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #btn-start-lives {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Livestream</h1>
    <section id="lives-container">
        <video id="lives-video" autoplay playsinline></video>
        <button id="btn-start-lives">Start</button>
        <button id="btn-end-lives">End</button>
    </section>

    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.0.0/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const socket = io('http://localhost:8080');
        const livesVideo = document.getElementById('lives-video');
        const btnStartLives = document.getElementById('btn-start-lives');
        const btnEndLives = document.getElementById('btn-end-lives');
        const roomId = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
        let stream;
        let pc = new RTCPeerConnection();

        pc.onicecandidate = event => {
            console.log("send:candidate");
            if (event.candidate) {
                socket.emit('candidate', { roomId, candidate: event.candidate });
            }
        }

        socket.on('offer', async (sdp) => {
            console.log("received:offer");
            stream.getTracks().forEach(track => pc.addTrack(track, stream));
            await pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription({ type: 'offer', sdp }));
            const answer = await pc.createAnswer();
            await pc.setLocalDescription(answer);
            console.log("send:answer");
            socket.emit('answer', { roomId, sdp: answer.sdp });
        });

        socket.on('candidate', async (candidate) => {
            console.log("received:candidate");
            try {
                await pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('Error adding received ice candidate', e);
            }
        });

        btnStartLives.addEventListener("click", async function () {
            stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
            livesVideo.srcObject = stream;
            livesVideo.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                livesVideo.play();
            };
            socket.emit('start-lives', { role: 'owner', roomId });
        });

        btnEndLives.addEventListener("click", async function () {
            stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
            pc.close();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>

caller.js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Livestream viewer</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <video id="remote-video"></video>
        <button id="btn-approval">See lives</button>
    </section>

    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.0.0/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const socket = io('http://localhost:8080');
        const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remote-video');
        const btnApproval = document.getElementById('btn-approval');
        const roomId = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
        let pc = new RTCPeerConnection();

        remoteVideo.onloadedmetadata = () => {
            remoteVideo.play();
        }

        pc.onicecandidate = event => {
            console.log("send:candidate");
            if (event.candidate) {
                socket.emit('candidate', { roomId, candidate: event.candidate });
            }
        }

        pc.ontrack = event => {
            console.log("trigger:ontrack");
            remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
        }
        
        btnApproval.addEventListener("click", async function () {
            // let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true });
            // stream.getTracks().forEach(track => pc.addTrack(track, stream));
            socket.emit('join', { roomId });
            const offer = await pc.createOffer();
            await pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
            console.log("send:offer");
            socket.emit('offer', { roomId, sdp: offer.sdp });
            this.remove();
        });

        socket.on('answer', async (sdp) => {
            console.log("received:answer");
            await pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription({ type: 'answer', sdp }));
        });

        socket.on('candidate', async (candidate) => {
            console.log("received:candidate");
            try {
                await pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('Error adding received ice candidate', e);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>

I try to log and not see any ice candidate triggered, my expected is the ice candidate gathering should be triggered because the setLocalDescription() is called

I don't see any stun server list in order to pick up a list of ice candidate
kind of code like the below

const iceServers = [
{ urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" },
{ urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:5349" },
{ urls: "stun:stun1.l.google.com:3478" },
{ urls: "stun:stun1.l.google.com:5349" },
{ urls: "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302" },
{ urls: "stun:stun2.l.google.com:5349" },
{ urls: "stun:stun3.l.google.com:3478" },
{ urls: "stun:stun3.l.google.com:5349" },
{ urls: "stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302" },
{ urls: "stun:stun4.l.google.com:5349" }

];
my free demo about webrtc

Your call setup is outdated.
The correct call setup flow should be as follows:

Create a data channel using RTCPeerConnection.createDataChannel() or
add a media track to the RTCPeerConnection object using RTCPeerConnection.addTrack().

The RTCPeerConnection.onnegotiationneeded event will be triggered after calling the above function.

In the RTCPeerConnection.onnegotiationneeded event handler, you must call RTCPeerConnection.setLocalDescription() without any parameters to generate the local description.

After that, the ice candidate event should be triggered.


You can refer to the examples provided on the following web page for more details:
WebRTC: Real-Time Communication in Browsers - Examples and Call Flows
